# Downloading a file and saving to a directory in PHP

Tags: php

SO i have a url of an mp3 file and i need to save it to a specific directory. How is the best way to do this, someone told me curl but is there a copy file of some php command that will make this process easier

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
copy($url, $destination);
```

[copy](http://nl.php.net/copy)

Comment: great answer! one additional hint: user 'dirname(...)' or an equivalent for $destination to get the relative server path

Comment: NOTE: The destination must include the file name and the directory must exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://amanjain.com/path-to-mp3.mp3');
//Create a new file where you want to save
$fp = fopen('filename.mp3', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy :-D

```
$URL = ...; //  Like "http:// ...."
$FileToSave = ...;     //  Like "/home/.." or "C:/..."
$Content = file_get_contents($URL);
file_put_contents($FileToSave, $Content);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure also you also modify your pages allowed execution time.  Most pages only allow 30 seconds, especially if you are doing this over a HTTP page (a webpage).  You need to up this to match how long it actually takes to download the file.