# A PHP Script that installs a file in a directory

Tags: php

I need a PHP script that installs a file like `example.php` into a specific directory. Any help would be appreciated.

I already have a script for making the directory. Here it is:

```
if (!file_exists("img/{$userName}")) {
    mkdir("img/{$userName}", 0777, true);
}
```

and the $userName variable is just a session variable:

```
$userName = $_SESSION["username"];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Mureinik I trying to make it using `fopen` and `fwrite`. I'll be back with an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the File come from? The user's harddrive, your webserver or anywhere from the web?
With `copy()` you can copy file from your webserver or the web to a local directory:

```
copy('https://url/file.jpg', 'destinationfolder/file.jpg');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Should the file be uploaded, use move_uploaded_file() in an upload script (see Example in Documentation:)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file

[edit]
The adavantage of using copy() over file_get_contents() is that the file content doesn't have to be read. Unless you want to do something with the contents of said file

Answer (score 0):

Try This Example with PHP :

```
$URL = ...; //  Like "http:// ...."
$FileToSave = ...;     //  Like "/home/.." or "C:/..."
$Content = file_get_contents($URL);
file_put_contents($FileToSave, $Content);
```

Attribution for @NawaMan in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532808/14945696)